Use go-lang handler function to process events from 2 trigger sources
I am writing a lambda function that can be triggered by 2 event sources - SQS or Dynamo Stream. They generate events that I want to process in my lambda and perform some business logic.
This is a sample body of the function -
func handlerFunction(ctx context.Context, event *MyEvent) (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("Received event: ", event, event.Records[0].Body)
    return "", nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!!")
    lambda.Start(handlerFunction)
}


handlerFunction is where the business logic to parse the event and invoke downstream components happen. Incoming events will be of different structure and cannot be handled the same way.
My question -
Can I use a if-else clause to direct events to different handler functions inside my lambda based on the message source.
Can one lambda function have 2 handlers inside it. In my case, 1 to process SQS events and other to process Dynamo streams.
Thank you

You can't have two handlers, but can multiplex yourself. You would lambda.Start(Handler):
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, event *DynamoDBOrSQSEvent) error {
    switch {
    case event.IsDynamoDBEvent():
        return DynamoDBHandler(ctx, &event.DynamoDBEvent)

    case event.IsSQSEvent():
        return SQSHandler(ctx, &event.SQSEvent)

    default:
        return ErrUnexpectedEvent
    }
}

func DynamoDBHandler(ctx context.Context, event *events.DynamoDBEvent) error {
    fmt.Printf("DynamoDBEvent records: %+v\n", event.Records)

    return nil
}

func SQSHandler(ctx context.Context, event *events.SQSEvent) error {
    fmt.Printf("SQSEvent records: %+v\n", event.Records)

    return nil
}

var ErrUnexpectedEvent = errors.New("unexpected event")

then define a structure that can hold a DynamoDBEvent or SQSEvent:
type DynamoDBOrSQSEvent struct {
    DynamoDBEvent events.DynamoDBEvent
    SQSEvent      events.SQSEvent
}

func (e *DynamoDBOrSQSEvent) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &e.DynamoDBEvent); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("can't unmarshal DynamoDB event: %w", err)
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &e.SQSEvent); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("can't unmarshal SQS event: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func (e *DynamoDBOrSQSEvent) IsDynamoDBEvent() bool {
    records := e.DynamoDBEvent.Records

    return len(records) > 0 && records[0].EventID != ""
}

func (e *DynamoDBOrSQSEvent) IsSQSEvent() bool {
    records := e.SQSEvent.Records

    return len(records) > 0 && records[0].MessageId != ""
}

Unmarshalling could be improved, but it should be enough for a proof of concept.
The question would be: What will be the advantage, since you won't be billed more for two separate lambda functions?

this is a great answer. Coming from Python background, leveraging struct to process these events make sense. regd 2 lambdas, I can be using 2 lambdas but there is business logic that I implement depend on both Dynamo and SQS actions. Would prefer to have them in the same fn.

A beginner question here regd using receiver types in the function definition. I see you have SQSHandler and DynamoDBHandler signatures without receiver in the function signature. However, you have receiver for IsDynamoDBEvent, IsSQSEvent functions. Why can't I just pass the event pointer to Is* functions, what warranted you to use receiver in the signature. Appreciate your time!

@Abhi I'm not sure I understand your questions fully. As you can see I wanted something that “magically” decoded the request, so that I can have the dispatch login in the main handler and have separate logic for both cases. In these cases there should be not dependency on the dispatch logic. After that, I wrote the dispatch logic and made it self contained, which means you can ask “which kind of message is it?” You can obviously model your logic differently.
